# Backdrop click not working with two mat-sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two right side nav. I want to fire backdrop event but its not working properly when I have up to side nav like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-container (backdropClick)="close()">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenavmenu position="end" class="sidenav-menu">
    <app-menu></app-menu>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenavnoti position="end" class="sidenav-noti">
    <app-notifications></app-notifications>
  </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container
```

Do you have any idea?